# entity framework core maximum classes by model

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I know that until EF6 is recommended that break project in small models/contexts, I remember that I saw something around 10 classes per context. Well, this still applicable for EF7 / Entity Framework Core ?

Answer (score 3):

The EF Core does not limit the number of entity types that can be added to a model. Models with high numbers of entity types only affects the performance of the initial model creation, but this model is cached so creation is only performed once per context type.

What has not changed from EF6, however, is that using LINQ queries on highly-connected graphs of many related entity types can result in slow, complex, or buggy behavior.

More info: checkout https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/efcore-vs-ef6/ for more information on comparing EF Core and EF 6, and https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/modeling/ for more information on modeling your database.

Comment: Well, but the initial model creation happen for each thread, right?, Can I load the context to be loaded for all my website requests ?

Comment: Two part question. (1) The cached model is a singleton (per process). (2) Assuming you are talking about ASP.NET, you should not share an instance of DbContext across web requests. As options and model building are cached, you don't pay a perf hit by creating a new context per request. See https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html for more docs on lifecycles of services.

Comment: Perfect, so I should avoid large models to avoid the loading time in my requests. Tks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you should avoid large models if you want to avoid a performance penalty on the **initial creation** of your model. That will only happen when the application first starts, not on each request. You should also test the performance of your model creation to establish whether you need to add the complexity of splitting your model between multiple contexts. 10 classes per context seems very unnecessary to me, unless they are completely huge classes...